# Flattening multiple queries into a single one

Tags: entity-framework-core

This doesn't work:

```
long[][] some2dArray = someTable.Select(x => new[] { x.SomeLongValue1, x.SomeLongValue2 }).ToArray();
var details = await db.SomeDetails
    .Where(x => some2dArray.Contains(new long[] { x.SomeLongValue1, x.SomeLongValue2 }))
    .ToArrayAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How can I make this work without turning it into:

```
        foreach(var item in some2dArray)
        {
            var details = await db.SomeDetails
                .Where(x => x.SomeLongValue1 == item[0] && x.SomeLongValue2 == item[1])
                .ToArrayAsync()
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

I don't like roundtrips - it is expensive.
Thx.

Thank you Svytoslav for your response, but your solution has errors:
[image]

One more error:
[image]

Comment: @M.A Corrected :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is universal, so you can use with other collections.

```cs
var details = await db.SomeDetails
    .FilterByItems(some2dArray, (x, a) => x.SomeLongValue1 == a[0] && x.SomeLongValue2 == a[0], true)
    .ToArrayAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

And implementation:

```cs
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> FilterByItems<T, TItem>(this IQueryable<T> query, IEnumerable<TItem> items,
        Expression<Func<T, TItem, bool>> filterPattern, bool isOr)
    {
        Expression predicate = null;
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var itemExpr = Expression.Constant(item);
            var itemCondition = ExpressionReplacer.Replace(filterPattern.Body, filterPattern.Parameters[1], itemExpr);
            if (predicate == null)
                predicate = itemCondition;
            else
            {
                predicate = Expression.MakeBinary(isOr ? ExpressionType.OrElse : ExpressionType.AndAlso, predicate,
                    itemCondition);
            }
        }

        predicate ??= Expression.Constant(false);
        var filterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(predicate, filterPattern.Parameters[0]);

        return query.Where(filterLambda);
    }

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

        public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
        }

        public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
                return replacement;
            return base.Visit(exp);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
        {
            return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
        }

        public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
        {
            if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
                throw new InvalidOperationException();

            return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
                .ToDictionary(i => (Expression) lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Could you please fix the code. I get an error:
"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'isOr' of QueryableExtensions<T...."

Comment: Could you please elaborate what does it do, and how does it work?

Comment: What is the problem? I have tested this code.

Comment: I posted the problem up there in question.

Comment: I have corrected code, to do not use `Zip`

Comment: So add `true` as last parameter if you need OR between predicates and `false` otherwise.

Comment: But I did that...please look closely, or if I don't understand something please clarify.

Comment: Oh, my bad, updated answer. Function requires second parameter IEnumerable,

Comment: Anyway, 2d arrays are not easily convertible to `IEnumerable`. Consider to do not use them.